# rails smart collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are rails smart collections?

If I am trying to build a view that presents most popular articles, top 10 products, recent comments (i.e a snapshot of recent updates to a variety of models in one view), would I be using a smart collection?

Would I be updating it via something like delayed job? Use some sort of fragment caching?

What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: yes I had no luck either, but I recently started using delayed job and I noticed the docs mentioning smart collection. I guess, regardless of what the terminology is, I am wondering how to best implement this top 10/most popular/recent type listings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of 'smart collections'.  That reference to them in the delayed_jobs docs seems to be the only one out there.  It would probably be better to email the author, he might have been referring to something that exists only in his head :)